Reference request: uniformly continuous semigroups of nonlinear (Lipschitz) operators
Consider a Banach space $X$ with norm $\vert\cdot\vert$, and call an operator $A\colon X\to X$ Lipschitz whenever
$$\sup_{f\neq g} \frac{\vert Af-Ag\vert}{\vert f-g\vert}<+\infty;$$
the Lipschitz operators then form a Banach space under the norm
$$ \Vert A \Vert = \vert A0\vert + \sup_{f\neq g} \frac{\vert Af-Ag\vert}{\vert f-g\vert}.$$
Note that a linear operator is Lipschitz if and only if it is bounded.
It is well-known that a family $(S_t)$ (indexed by $t\geq0$) of bounded linear operators on $X$ is a uniformly continuous (that is, w.r.t. $\Vert\cdot\Vert$)) semigroup if and only if there is some bounded linear operator $A$ such that
$$S_t=e^{tA}=\lim_{n\to+\infty} \left(I+\frac{t}{n}A\right)^n 
\text{for all } t\geq 0,$$in which case
$$A = \lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{S_t-I}{t}.$$
I think I'm able to prove that a similar result holds for uniformly continuous semigroups of (1-)Lipschitz operators. I can't imagine that I'm the first to think about this, but I haven't been able to locate a reference where this is established (or mentioned). Hence my question: can anyone point me to work that considers uniform (rather than strong or weak) continuity for semigroups of (1-)Lipschitz (so "contracting" or "non-expanding") nonlinear operators?
